# Guess 7 times loop (Basic Java)

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I am working on the 1-100 guessing number with high or low if not correct guess until 7 times will lose the game unless you've won the right guessed number. I tried to add with while loop and if statement `if (guess1 <8) break;` should stop or break the running program I used is Unix Terminal.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Games {
   public static void main(String[] args){

      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

      Random rand = new Random();
      int tries;
      int correctNum = rand.nextInt(100);
      int count = 7;

      //int guess1 = input.nextInt();
      while(true){

         System.out.println("Pick a number between 1-100");
         int guess1 = input.nextInt();

         if(guess1 < correctNum){
            System.out.println("Too low!");
         } else if(guess1 > correctNum){
            System.out.println("Too high!");
         } else if(guess1 == correctNum){
            System.out.println("Correct!");
         } else{
            System.out.println("hmm, try again");
         }

         if (guess1<8) break;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Actually , guess1 is the Input the user make, the variable you want to check to loop is count. You should start count at 1 instead of 7 and increment it every iteration of the while. also you can juste make your condition in the while `while(count < 8){` instead of a `if (guess1<8) break;

Comment: `Games.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
        while(guess1 < 8){
              ^
  symbol:   variable guess1
  location: class Games
1 error`

Comment: `guess1` is the input that user enters. Create another variable to keep track of `attempts` Also you can use do while here. It executes the code and then checks the condition. while checks the condition the then execute the code.

Answer (score 0):

Your break condition is not correct. To keep track of how many times the loop has run you might wanna initialize `tries` and increment it by one in your loop. Also change `if (guess1<8) break;`to `if (tries > count) break;` so as to make sure that the loop doesn't not run more than `count` (7) times.

Answer (score -2):

Change `while(true)` to a for loop and iterate only 7 times.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 7; ++i) {

    //Remove the if (guess1<8) break;
}
```